# Kafka consumer partition reprocessing uncommitted messages on pause and resume

Tags: apache-kafka

I am looking for an option to reprocess uncommitted messages after kafka consumer pause and resume. Could some one suggest me on best approach to be used for that?. Choose pause/resume instead of stopping and restarting consumer to avoid rebalancing as part of error handling in the application.

Rebalancing wise it's working fine as we expected with pause / resume the container , but only thing is it's not reprocessing the uncommitted message after resume. Is there any way we could re process those uncommitted messages?

Other issue facing with stop and restarting is , as soon as start the consumer after stopping in error scenario, consumer is able to pickup uncommitted messages and retrying it without incrementing offset as expected. While this process is continuing if I publish any other message which can process successfully, then after it's not picking up previous failed/uncommitted message as it is looking for the messages from the next offset in the polling. How could we handle this scenario?

If seek to current offset is an option, could some one provide any working example with seek to current offset implementation at this scenario?

In brief , the configuration provided is :

-> processing single record instead of batch processing.
-> Enable Auto Commit Config provided as false and following MANUAL_IMMEDIATE ack mode.
-> Using kafkaListenerContainerFactory  with concurrency defined as 1.

Greatly appreciate suggestions on this!

Comment: try save your offset into you database

Comment: We are actually not referring any database in our use case.

Comment: without store offset yourself，reprocess record is hard

Comment: Trying with seek to failed offset before calling resume in error scenario.

Here I don’t know how to get access of kafka consumer to call seek operation in custom error handler, which is subscribed to topic defined in listener method using spring kafka listener.